# CodeIgniter: The upload path does not appear to be valid

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I am getting this error in the upload functionality for CodeIgniter Image upload.

**The upload path does not appear to be valid**

This problem started happening after I uploaded the site from my local system to my live system.

I am adding my code below. I don't know what is wrong. I have gone through all the other forums on this. But nothing helped.

```
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);     
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
```

The folder has full permissions, and as I said it was working on my local system. Not sure what the issue could be. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the path of the folder **uploads** is in project root?. At the end of the path you need to use **/** like `$config['upload_path'] = "uploads/";`

Comment: Try just `$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';` Make sure you have correct folder permissions.

Answer (score 3):

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads';
```

`upload path` directory must be writable and the path can be absolute or relative.  If your uploads folder is in your document root then `./uploads/` should work or `FCPATH . 'uploads/'` (check if FCPATH has a trailing slash, if not add it to uploads).

Aside from that the path has to exist, CodeIgniter won't make the directory for you.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to debug your `upload_path`. I have the same case and I solved it. The problem is the path whether your path has been set correctly or not.

In my case:

```
$config = array(
  'upload_path' => FCPATH."application/upload",
  'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
);
```

The `FCPATH` is the your project file path. Hope this would help others.